# XMLHttpRequest will sometimes fail for an available resource

Tags: javascript, get, apache2, xmlhttprequest

It's a problem I don't really understand and can't seem to fix. Basically I'll make an XMLHttpRequest to my server to get a file. I KNOW the file exists, but sometimes this request will simply fail to get the file and I'm not sure why. It's essentially this

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, true);
req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

req.onload = function(e) { // Do stuff with file }
req.failure = function() { console.log('file load failure'); }
req.send(null);
```

But sometimes it won't be able to get the file and I'll check the console and see the last line *req.send(null);* referenced. I'm a bit confused why this is happening and, more importantly, why it only happens sometimes.

My server runs apache2 if that helps

Comment: Does the failure() code get triggered? If yes, did you look at what was returned.

Comment: I don't think it does. I never see the error message printed in the console

Comment: pls show more code, what is url? and i assume  // Do stuff with file } is just for sample since you commented out the closing bracket }

Comment: Shouldn't you be using onerror and not failure?

Comment: Try pasting the `url` you're fetching into a separate browser tab to verify that it loads [reliably], to eliminate that as a possible source of error.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it definitely exists and loads reliably although it's hard to test. The URL is a file that is generated on the server, so we have a pinger that checks that it exists (using Django and pythons os.path.exists()) and when it says it does we then load it